# how to add text and values to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
{
    
    "user": "someuser",
    "message": "need a help"
},
{
    "user": "bot",
    "message": "can i help you?"
},
{
    "user": "someuser",
    "message": "another question"
}
```

I need to read additional paragraphs on the page and add them to my json - object, for sending to the server. The positions can be around 10-20!
.edited-phrase and .phrase-return is what is already on the page in .client-mess and .bot-mess I fill in the data from json. Sending ajax is not a problem, the problem is to form correct data(

The final version should look like this:

```
   {
        "user": "someuser",
        "message": "need a help"
        "edited": "hello",
        "return": "return on step_1",
    },
   
 {
        "user": "bot",
        "message": "can i help you?"
  }

  {
        "user": "someuser",
        "message": "another question"
        "edited": "forget",
        "return": "return on step_3",
 },
```

Thank you in advance!

```
  <div class="message-row">
    <div class="client-say">
      <p class="client-mess" data-user="someuser">need a help</p>
      <div class="return-container">
        <p class="edited-phrase">hello</p>
        <p class="phrase-return">return on step_1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-row">
    <div class="bot-say">
      <p class="bot-mess" data-user="bot">can i help you?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-row">
    <div class="client-mess data-user="someuser"">
      <p class="phrase-return">another question</p>
      <div class="return-container">
        <p class="edited-phrase">forget</p>
        <p class="phrase-return">return on step_3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
  <a id="sendJson" href="#" class="" >send Json</a>
  </div>
</div>


$('#sendJson').on('click', function() {
    var messagesArray = [];
    $dialogMessages = {};
   $(".container .message-row")
    .each(function () {
    
        $dialogMessages = {
        
            user:$(this).data('user'),
            
          
            
            /* message:$(this).text(),
            phraseEdited: ,
            phraseReturn: , */
            
            
        }

        messagesArray.push($dialogMessages);

    });
     
 })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im edit question,I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

In browser environment, you can use querySelectorAll method:

```
const paragraphsWithClassReturn = document.querySelectorAll('p.return');
```

See [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on MDN.

After this, you can turn the result into an array and loop through it using available array methods:

```
Array.from(paragraphsWithClassReturn).forEach(paragraph => {
    // your code doing something with every found paragraph
})
```

In jQuery, you select elements having return class using

```
const $paragraphsWithClassReturn = $('p.return')
```

...and then loop through them with .each method:

```
$paragraphsWithClassReturn.each($paragraph => {
    // your code doing something with every found paragraph
});
```